# Can't access Javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm using webform asp.net and C#. I linked the master page with javascript file like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
```

but when I'm going to inner pages inside folders.. I can't access the JavaScript file.. (404 error).I tried to solve the problem by using ResolveClientUrl but it's not work!
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> but when I'm going to inner pages inside folders.. I can't access the JavaScript file

Since the page you're accessing is at a different level than your master page, you want to make the script path relative to the root of your application

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/main.js"></script>
```

---

**EDIT** if that's not working, then I would keep the script tag as it is above, run it in Chrome with the developer tools / network tab open, and look at the exact address that shows up for the failed request.  Then look closely at your application and see what's different / wrong.

Comment: No. I'm sure that it's not at a different level.. i used firebug to make sure from this issue.

Comment: @dotWasim you just said in the question that the inner pages are inside folders, and now you're saying that it's not at a different level. Only one of these things can be true.

Comment: @dotWasim - have you tried changing the script tag to what's above?

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm sure from this point.every single character is correct! but iis return 404 error!

Comment: @dotWasim - there may be a problem with IIS somewhere.  Have you tried browsing to this javascript file by itself?

Comment: Yes it's return HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: @dotWasim - it sounds like you have some sort of problem with IIS - not your script tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/javascript/main.js") %>" />
```

Allows you to use ASP.NETs `~`. If this doesn't work then the file doesn't exist in that directory.

Comment: Dear @webnoob I did that..the problem didn't caused because my link was not correct.